# Can't get options values from form symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

as the tittle says I can't get those values, here's my code:

I got this form (not mapped):

```
$default = array('default' => '');

$form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($default)
    ->add('Users', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $info,
     ))
    ->getForm();
```

Where $info Is an array of strings.

And I'm trying to access to the data like this:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

    $data = $this->get('request')->request->get('form');
    $user = implode(",", $data);
}
```

But the result I'm getting is something like this:

0,ACARxcur37cumZiRm5AmmyRJdC5UpuO1hb43I5LFx2A

I assume that the 0 is the selected index but, why am I getting that code? Looks like got some format.

Trying the way Kris suggested like this:

```
    $default = array('default' => '');
    $info = array();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($default)
            ->add('Users', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $info,
            ))
            ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    //1st try:
    $data = $form2->get('Users')->getConfig()->getOption('choices');

    //2nd try:
    $data = $form2->get('Users');
```

In the first try I get nothing it appears to be empty.

In the second try I get an error.

PD: I need to get the selected value, not the full field.

Thanks for reading, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the form using the Symfony way.

So instead of doing

`($request->getMethod() == 'POST)`
Use the form to actually get the data not $_REQUEST

would do this

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if($form->isValid()) {
   $data = $form->get('Users')->getData();
}
```

Comment: tryed that way but how do I build the form? I mean in $form->handleRequest($request); I must build that form before right?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, as I thought the "0" in the result "0,ACARxcur37cumZiRm5AmmyRJdC5UpuO1hb43I5LFx2A" was in fact the option value, so the solution was changing that value when building $info.

Instead of:

array_push($info,$user);

I did:
$info[$user] = [$user];

That way the option value and label contains the same.

Thanks everyone.